# MySql result into grouped multi-dimensional array, I'm missing something

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, multidimensional-array

Could some fresh eyes please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I'm sure it's something simple.

The sql query that retrieves the data set:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category='category' ORDER BY publish_date DESC, id DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

The multidimensional array that I am trying to reach:

```
list [ 
    publish_date [
        0 [ id, title, body ]
        1 [ id, title, body ]
        2 [ id, title, body ]]
    publish_date [
        0 [ id, title, body ]
        1 [ id, title, body ]]
    publish_date [
        0 [ id, title, body ]
        1 [ id, title, body ]
        2 [ id, title, body ]
        3 [ id, title, body ]]]
Etc..
```

I have been fiddling with the following php function for a few hours now:

```
$result = $sql->prepareQuery($query_string);

// iterate through array and place results in an array at row index
$list = ['group_date' => ' '];
$r = 0;
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($list['publish_date'] != $rows['pub_date']) {
        $list['publish_date'] = $rows['pub_date'];
        $r = 0;
        foreach ($rows as $key => $val) {
            $list['publish_date'][$r[$key = $val]];
        }
        $r++;
    }
    else {
        foreach ($rows as $key => $val) {
            $list['publish_date'][$r[$key = $val]];
        }
        $r++;
    }
}
// return result
print_r($list);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you are making things to complicated:

```
$list = array();
$current_date = '';
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($current_date != $rows['pub_date']) {
        $current_date = $rows['pub_date'];
        $list[$current_date] = array();
    }
    $list[$current_date][] = $rows;
}
```

Comment: Works great.. not sure who down graded you, but from me, thanks.

Comment: Yeah I would like to know also, someone probably downvoted simply because you are using a mysql_* function. But that wasn't the point of the question or answer. If that is the case you can change it to `while($rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {`

Comment: Thanks again. Added my final function to OP.